# Are the reckoning effect Lore checks on Glamour cards considered spell effects?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-strange-remnants

The Unique Asset "Sealing the Old Ones" allows one to discard spells when a Lore check is passed as a Spell Effect.  Glamour Spells from the Strange Remnants expansion don't have a Lore check in the standard main body of the spell, but rather have Lore checks as part of their reckoning effects, as if they are ongoing spell effects that get checked every reckoning for any side effects.

Does this reckoning effect Lore check count as a spell effect for the purposes of deciding to discard it to add an eldritch token to the Sealing the Old Ones Unique Asset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/39/c1/39c182c1-6b0d-46c4-b5eb-dd6886b4c798/eh01_reference_guide1.pdf), page 11:

> An investigator can resolve a Spell card's effect as described on the
>   card. A Spell card’s effect may be triggered by a specific event or
>   require an action.

The rules don't explicitly define a "Spell Effect", so we use the above to determine that it means the effect of a Spell card, whether cast or activated otherwise.